# How to maintain variable type when using a function in applescript

Tags: list, function, types, applescript

I'm writing a script that will constantly scan iTunes for new dialog boxes and close them correctly depending on what they do. For the most part my script is working correctly with the exception that it doesn't search the buttons of the dialog box.

So far the script will wait until another process opens iTunes, and then wait for the first dialog box to appear (using spin-wait loops). Once a dialog box appears it gets the window and then the window's buttons. I would like it to then make decisions based on what the buttons are, but I'm having a bad time with finding out what the buttons are. Below is the entire script:

```
#repeat
set windowOpen to false
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until windowOpen
        if window 1 of process "iTunes" exists then
            set windowOpen to true
        end if
    end repeat
    set windowOpen to false
    tell process "iTunes"
        set frontmost to true
        set wantedWindow to null
        repeat until windowOpen
            try
                set wantedWindow to first UI element whose role description is "dialog"
                set windowOpen to true
            on error erMessg
                set windowOpen to false
            end try
        end repeat
        set buttonList to every button in wantedWindow
        if (count of buttonList) is 1 then
            if title of item 1 of buttonList is not "Stop" then
                click item 1 of buttonList
            end if
        else
            if my windowContainsButton(buttonList, "Cancel") then
                say "Cancel"
            end if
            #           repeat with theButton in buttonList
            #               if title of theButton is "Cancel" or title of theButton is "Restore" then
            #                   say "cancel"
            #                   delay 1
            #               end if
            #           end repeat
        end if
    end tell
    set wantedWindow to null
end tell
#end repeat
on windowContainsButton(listOfButtons, searchFor)
    repeat with theButton in listOfButtons
        if title of theButton is searchFor then
            return true
        end if
    end repeat
    return false
end windowContainsButton
```

So far, I'm trying to find out if it has found a cancel button by having it say "Cancel". Instead, it's coming up with an error: `System Events got an error: Can't make |title| of button "Cancel" of window 1 of application process "iTunes" into type reference.` It then points me to my function windowContainsButton on this line:

```
if title of theButton is searchFor then
```

and it highlights searchFor.

The windowContainsButton function is exactly the commented out section of code, just generalized. The commented out section works, which is a large part of the reason I'm asking about types.

First off, how can I go about implementing a function like this? Lets say that I actually wanted this function to work, how could I make it?

Secondly, is there a better way to do this? I don't mean the entire script (although I wouldn't doubt that it could be done better), I mean searching the buttons for a particular button that I'm expecting.

edit: another thing I noticed is that "title" is a reserved word in the body of the script, but a variable in the function. I'm used to other languages where reserved words are reserved universally, so I would also like some guidance with what's going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not gone through the whole script but this should fix your handler:

```
on windowContainsButton(listOfButtons, searchFor)
    repeat with theButton in listOfButtons
        tell application "System Events"
            if title of theButton is searchFor then return true
        end tell
    end repeat
    return false
end windowContainsButton
```

This is a bit cleaner:

```
    property theSeconds : 1

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until window 1 of process "iTunes" exists
        delay theSeconds
    end repeat
    tell process "iTunes"
        set frontmost to true
        repeat until exists (first UI element whose role description is "dialog")
            delay theSeconds
        end repeat
        set wantedWindow to first UI element whose role description is "dialog"
        tell wantedWindow
            set buttonList to title of every button in wantedWindow
            if (count of buttons) is 1 and title of button 1 is not "Stop" then
                click button 1
            else if buttonList contains "Cancel" then
                say "Cancel"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I had tried adding the System Events tell outside of the repeat block and it didn't change anything, but this worked. And ideas why?

Comment: tell app "System Events" works outside of the repeat block within the handler. Without it, you have a new variable named title.